# how to check if i have cuda installed, i came across three methods but they give me different results

Tags: linux, cuda, pytorch

I know that it might be because i dont have the toolkit installed but can someone please elaborate why *smi shows cuda-10.1 while nvcc and /usr/local/cuda/version.txt  don't return anything*
i want to install pytorch and use the gpu for training so should i go with cuda toolkit?

**(base) e@c:~$ nvidia-smi**
Wed May 13 05:03:08 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       **CUDA Version: 10.1**     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 930M        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    616MiB /  2004MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2004      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           194MiB |
|    0      2253      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         159MiB |
|    0      2703      G   /proc/self/exe                               259MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

**(base) e@c:~$ nvcc --version
Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit**

**(base) e@c:~$ cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
cat: /usr/local/cuda/version.txt: No such file or directory**